# Android VideoView not showing up in different Layout

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-framelayout

First of all I've already looked at similar questions on the site and they didn't help.I am using FrameLayout and trying to click on custom ImageView so that the imageview gets invisible and the video starts playing but when I click on the ImageView only a blank screen comes up and no video/audio plays.

```
feedImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            String substrr=item.getURL();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            vid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(substrr);
                            vid.setVideoURI(vidUri);

                            MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(getActivity());
                            vidControl.setAnchorView(vid);
                            vid.setMediaController(vidControl);
                         vid.start();

        });
```

The complete layout where they go is below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/feed_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right" >

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/profilePic"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" >
            </com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_profile_name"
                    android:textColor="#0f84cc"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


       <-- THIS IS THE FRAME LAYOUT CONCERNED WITH THE QUESTION-->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <com.example.android.FeedImageView
            android:id="@+id/feedImage1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="visible" />

            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/vid12"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                />

            </FrameLayout>
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtStatusMsg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_top" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/downloadbtn" 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Download"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#0f84cc"
                />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now the video works if I use the java code with the following layout -

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.videoplayer.MainActivity">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myPic"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"

    />
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/myVideo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Please help.

Comment: any error are you getting?

Comment: @Shoeb Siddique No error.I just can't get the VideoView in the first layout to show up and I get no sound either.

Answer (score 0):

U need to remove android:visibility = "invisible" from belowXML..

```
  <VideoView
    android:id="@+id/myVideo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Comment: I need to set the visibility of the video as invisible first and only visible when the imageview is clicked.The videoView with id myVideo works fine and is a part of different layout which works for the code.What I'm asking is what changes should i make to layout with videoview(having id vid12) to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to play video in separate thread -

Setup the video player and URLs in the `runOnUiThread`.

```
feedImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    String substrr=item.getURL();
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        feedImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        vid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(substrr);
                vid.setVideoURI(vidUri);

                MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(getActivity());
                vidControl.setAnchorView(vid);
                vid.setMediaController(vidControl);
                vid.start();
            }
        });



    });
```